how can I properly finish a client-initiated TCP 4-way teardown (Close() isn't working)?
I am writing both a client and server in GO, and want to have the option to change between UDP and TCP for the same single piece of data that needs communicating. (Im using TCP for less reliable network links)
The client appears to be operating fine, but the server is not completing the TCP 4 way teardown that the client initiates (despite calling Close() at the end of the server connection handling loop)
While doing a packet capture, I see that if I kill the server pid, it suddenly does the last bit of the TCP teardown.
I think the defer listener.Close() is finishing the teardown, but I don't want to close the listener everytime a connection is over.
How can I make it finish the teardown at the end of the for loop?
Why isn't tcpConn.Close() finishing the teardown?
Server snippet:
func serverModeTCP(listenAddress string, confRemoteAddr string, filterMessage string) {
        // Start local listener
        listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", listenAddress)
        logError("failed to create local TCP listener", err, true)
        defer listener.Close()

        // Notify
        fmt.Printf("Server started, listening on TCP socket %s\n", listenAddress)

        // Wait for data in receive buffer and process
        recvBuffer := make([]byte, 1448)
        for {
                // Accept incoming connection
                tcpConn, err := listener.Accept()
                if err != nil {
                        logMessage(fmt.Sprintf("Failed: error accepting TCP connection: %v", err))
                        tcpConn.Close()
                        continue
                }

                // Write payload into buffer
                recvDataLen, err := tcpConn.Read(recvBuffer)
                if err != nil {
                        logMessage(fmt.Sprintf("Failed: reading packet payload resulted in error: %v", err))
                        tcpConn.Close()
                        continue
                }

                // Get remote address for filter
                remoteAddr := tcpConn.RemoteAddr()

                // Read from buffer
                receivedText := recvBuffer[:recvDataLen]

                // Process received packet
                BreakLoop := ParsePayload(receivedText, remoteAddr.String(), confRemoteAddr, filterMessage)

                // Close connection and exit server if requested
                tcpConn.Close()
                if BreakLoop {
                        break
                }
        }
}

func ParsePayload(receivedText []byte, remoteAddr string, confRemoteAddr string, filterMessage string) bool {
        // Check correct network endpoint
        if remoteAddr != confRemoteAddr {
                logMessage(fmt.Sprintf("Failed: received Invalid Packet from %s. IP or Port incorrect.", remoteAddr))
                return false
        }

        // Check message validity against config string or validity
        if string(receivedText) != filterMessage {
                logMessage(fmt.Sprintf("Failed: received Invalid Packet from %s. Message Data is incorrect.", remoteAddr))
                return false
        }
        
        // break processing loop and allow server to exit
        return true
}

Client snippet:
func clientConnect(filterMessage string, listenAddress string, remoteAddress string) {
        // Byte msg
        Text := []byte(filterMessage)

        // Resolve remote addr and local addr
        listenSocket, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", listenAddress)
        logError("failed to resolve remote host address", err, true)
        remoteSocket, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", remoteAddress)
        logError("failed to resolve remote host address", err, true)

        // Connect to remote - open socket
        socket, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", listenSocket, remoteSocket)
        logError("failed to connect to remote host", err, true)

        // Send the message to the remote host
        _, err = socket.Write(Text)
        logError("failed to send message", err, true)

        // Notify
        fmt.Printf("Sent Packet to %s\n", remoteAddress)

        // Cleanup
        socket.Close()
}

After client has exited, the connection state as appearing to the system is:
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3493          127.0.0.1:49573         CLOSE_WAIT  1807/sol   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:49573         127.0.0.1:3493          FIN_WAIT2   -                   

Packet capture of the full connection
10:34:38.277607 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30400, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [S], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0x9c34), seq 3628317905, win 65495, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 675489578 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:34:38.277616 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    127.0.0.1.3493 > 127.0.0.1.49573: Flags [S.], cksum 0xfe30 (incorrect -> 0x4e28), seq 2871677807, ack 3628317906, win 65483, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 675489578 ecr 675489578,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:34:38.277625 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30401, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x74e4), seq 1, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675489578 ecr 675489578], length 0
10:34:38.277662 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30402, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 119)
    127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [P.], cksum 0xfe6b (incorrect -> 0x8d4f), seq 1:68, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675489578 ecr 675489578], length 67
10:34:38.277666 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39324, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.3493 > 127.0.0.1.49573: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x74a1), seq 1, ack 68, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675489578 ecr 675489578], length 0
10:34:38.277677 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 30403, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x74a0), seq 68, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675489578 ecr 675489578], length 0
10:34:38.321141 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39325, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.3493 > 127.0.0.1.49573: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x7474), seq 1, ack 69, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675489622 ecr 675489578], length 0

    #### MISSING 127.0.0.1.3493 > 127.0.0.1.49573: Flags [F.]
    #### MISSING 127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [.]
    
#### CLIENT PROGRAM HAS EXITED BY HERE

10:34:53.389147 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39326, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.3493 > 127.0.0.1.49573: Flags [.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0x3999), seq 0, ack 69, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675504690 ecr 675489578], length 0
10:34:53.389167 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [.], cksum 0x396c (correct), seq 69, ack 1, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675504690 ecr 675489622], length 0
    
#### SERVER PID IS KILLED HERE

10:35:02.392670 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 39327, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.3493 > 127.0.0.1.49573: Flags [F.], cksum 0xfe28 (incorrect -> 0xdb63), seq 1, ack 69, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675513693 ecr 675504690], length 0
10:35:02.392681 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    127.0.0.1.49573 > 127.0.0.1.3493: Flags [.], cksum 0xb838 (correct), seq 69, ack 2, win 512, options [nop,nop,TS val 675513693 ecr 675513693], length 0

Full go source file:
https://paste.debian.net/hidden/e8eb30ec/
Config that goes with it (keys are for testing, nothing secret about them):
{
  "listenIP": "127.0.0.1",
  "listenPort": "49573",
  "remote":
  [
    {
    "IP": "127.0.0.1",
    "Port": "3493"
    }
  ],
  "authKey": "eda93e096f02c8ee5dff91d5d911cfb3",
  "authIV": "cc6399259b2cd84efa9371cb",
  "filterMessage": "shutdownserver",
  "remoteLog":
  {
    "enabled": false,
    "syslogDestinationIP": "127.0.0.1",
    "syslogDestinationPort": "1514"
  },
  "fileLog":
  {
    "enabled": false,
    "logPath": "/var/log/sol.log"
  }
}


"Why isn't tcpConn.Close() finishing the teardown?" - are you sure it is even called? There is a call of ParsePayload before that - no idea what this does and if it ever returns so that tcpConn.Close() could be called.

Yeah, that function just checks IP and payload, it returns always.

The client code here doesn't call Close(), it needs to do that to shutdown the connection cleanly

@JimB No go there, (added the socket.Close()), client iniates the teardown but the server is not continuing leaving the socket waiting.

The server must read until io.EOF to know if the connection is being shut down remotely (and the inverse is true for the client). Not to mention you may not have read the entire message with a single Read call, which should always be in a loop and checking for EOF after handling read bytes. Your construction here has both sides assuming they are initiating the close, with neither confirming that has happened.

That makes sense, but wouldn't a for loop for reading just break at EOF and call Close() anyway? So while I may be assuming things about the length of data received, its functionality equivalent to what you are saying (at least for my small 67 byte payload)?

@bdrun33, yes if they both call Close it should still work even though the protocol is ambiguous, but something is not working correctly for you, so I'm pointing out potential problems with your code that should be fixed anyway. Really without a complete [mre] we're only going to be guessing here. (a simple example based on your code does close the connection completely, while skipping the Close in the server will result in a half-closed connection with CLOSE_WAIT and FIN_WAIT_2)

Ill update the post with the full program. I did find something interesting though. If I move the tcpConn.Close() above the buffer read line, the server then sends a fin ack after the clients fin ack, but in netstat, the client is stuck in a TIME_WAIT. One step forward I suppose.

it's not "stuck", TIME_WAIT is normal for the client side of the connection.

Ah yes. Welp, looks like its solved then. Not sure if the earlier close is entirely 'robust', since it seems like the time it takes for the parsing function is to blame.

No, randomly closing the connection is not robust when you don't know if you've received everything or not. Whatever application layer protocol you are using should leave one side of the connection responsible for closing, and the other in a state waiting for that signal.
